# Merging of dataframes based off substrings in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have two data frames, one (df_protein) contains experimental measured data from protein fragments carrying a modification, in the other (df_modificaton) I have a database of the "name" off all modification. Now I am trying to merge those together.

Both have a column with the modified sequence (the amino acid which is modified has an asterisk). But in df_protein the sequence of the whole fragment (!) is stored (starting and ending with "*"), while in df_modification only the 7 amino acids before and after the modification are given (if it is at the start or the end of the protein the remaining places are marked with "*")

For better illustration here a MWE:

```
df_protein <- data_frame(
  Protein = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Sequence = c("_EPTPSIASDIY*LPIATQELR_" , "_S*SSSLLASPGHISVK_", "_SSS*SLLASPGHISVK_", "_TQDPVPPET*PSDSDHK_", "_SMS*VDLSHIPLK_") ,
  Counts = c(3.456, 6.126, 10.023 ,0.000, 7.250)
)

df_modificaton <- data_frame(
  Protein = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  Sequence = c("TIPEQRLS*SSSLLAS", "PSIASDIY*LPIATQ", "PEQRLSSS*SLLASPG", "DPVPPET*PSDSDHK", "FYYEILNS*PEKACSL","_____SMS*VDLSHIP"), 
  Modification = c("S125", "Y77", "S127", "T456", "S44", "S3")
)

# How can I merge the above to the following result:
df_merged <- data_frame(
  Protein = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Sequence = c("_EPTPSIASDIY*LPIATQELR_" , "_S*SSSLLASPGHISVK_", "_SSS*SLLASPGHISVK_", "_TQDPVPPET*PSDSDHK_", "_SMS*VDLSHIPLK_") ,
  Counts = c(3.456, 6.126, 10.023 ,0.000, 7.250),
  Modification = c("Y77", "S125", "S127", "T456", "S3")
)
```

I am using `tidyverse` but I am also fine with other packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the `fuzzyjoin` package to perform a `stringdist` join:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_inner_join(df_protein, df_modificaton,
                      by = "Sequence", method = "jw", distance_col = "distance") %>%
  group_by(Sequence.x) %>%
  slice_min(distance)
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   Sequence.x [5]
  Protein.x Sequence.x              Counts Protein.y Sequence.y       Modification distance
  <chr>     <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>            <chr>           <dbl>
1 A         _EPTPSIASDIY*LPIATQELR_   3.46 A         PSIASDIY*LPIATQ  Y77             0.260
2 A         _S*SSSLLASPGHISVK_        6.13 A         PEQRLSSS*SLLASPG S127            0.294
3 B         _SMS*VDLSHIPLK_           7.25 B         _____SMS*VDLSHIP S3              0.15 
4 A         _SSS*SLLASPGHISVK_       10.0  A         PEQRLSSS*SLLASPG S127            0.294
5 B         _TQDPVPPET*PSDSDHK_       0    B         DPVPPET*PSDSDHK  T456            0.137
```

Comment: Looks nice. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just realized that I was a bit too quick. In your output row 2 the Sequence "PEQRLSSS*SLLASPG" was matched, while in fact it should be "TIPEQRLS*SSSLLAS". 
It looks more on the overall sequence and doesn't put enoughweight on the asterisk. I maybe it would be helpful to trim/expand the sequence in a way that always the asterisk is in the middle.

Comment: There are many ways you can tweak the distance algorithm see [`help(stringdist)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.4.6/topics/stringdist) for more details.

Comment: You might also try removing the `_`s, I don't think that's helping.